# Start Outlook with c#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Can I make C# start Outlook in the code?

In VB6 we use object 'Outlook.Application' and write:'

```
Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set oNameSpace = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set oInbox = oNameSpace.Folders(1) 
 'Set oInbox = oInbox.Folders("Inbox")
oInbox.Display 
 'oOutlook.Quit 'Close All Outlook copies
```

Copy/Paste from link: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=73886

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to start the outlook; using [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) would be the easiest way. :)

Answer (score 7):

`System.Diagnostics.Process` will only start a process.

To do additional actions such choosing folders, you need to use Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO). And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx) is it's reference. For example:

```
var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
outlook.Quit();
```

Comment: I am told that when using Office interop, never use the XXXClass classes.  I think you mean var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting opinion. Do you know why - don't use? I have an application with complex Excel-to-Excel data processing where there a lot of Excel.ApplicationClass classes usings. Everything works absolutely correctly! Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application.aspx is an interface, isn't it?

Comment: Using Application works if Outlook is already running but it won't invoke a new instance of Outlook.  I had to use ApplicationClass which will either use an existing instance or invoke a new instance if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You could use its ProgID to get the type and the activator

```
Type objectType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application");
object outlook = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
```

But using this in C# you will lose all type information (i.e. no IntelliSense) and you need to call some ugly method to invoke the operations with LateBinding (google for Type.Invoke)

Other option is add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass, so you have compile time type information and create an instance for Outlook in the usual way

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass outlook 
     = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
```

Or you could use my [Late Binding Helper](http://code.google.com/p/latebindinghelper) library and use it like this

```
Invoker outlook = BindingFactory.CreateAutomationBinding("Outlook.Application");
outlook.Method("Quit").Invoke();
```

No Intellisense with this one, but at least the library will save you from the ugly calls to Type.Invoke and give you a fluent interface instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works (you might have to change the path to what it is on the machine on which the app will run):

```
public static void StartOutlookIfNotRunning()
{
    string OutlookFilepath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE";
    if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0) return;
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(OutlookFilepath);
    process.Start();
}
```